# pass variable to asp through json.parse

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net

I have a function in VB Code behind that uses parameters and outputs a `datatable` for the front end to use for placing markers on google-maps. From the front, I need to send a variable that the user enters.

**Javascript Pseudo:**

```
if (a = true){
    var varName = inputBox.value;
    var passer1 = chkCondition1();
    var passer2 = chkCondition2();

    if (passer1 == true && passer2 == true) {
        Coordinates = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertTabletoString(varName) %>');
    }
else {
    //do other stuff
     }
```

I'm getting the error:

> Error 2   'varName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

I'm not sure what to do here.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: What's inside the `<%=ConvertTableto...blabla... %>` is executed serverside in your VB, so it doesn't know anything about varName which lives in your javascript.

Comment: Gotcha.  So I'd have to pass that variable to the back-end. I remember seeing ways to do that with a hidden field but it feels hacky, is that the accepted way to do that?

Comment: Coming to webforms from an mvc background I also found hidden fields a weird way of doing things but it's quite acceptable I think. Sometimes you might be better off using AJAX calls from your javascript though, it depends. The hidden field would need to be read from the serverside after you set it, so how is that going to be fired? You probably then need an `asp:button` on your page too which reads the hiddenfield in it's click event on your serverside, then if your javascript needs to handle the response...? So yeah ajax calls can be easier sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem you have is that the variable you want to use on server-side does not exist on the server, moreover, does not exist at the client-side either at the point you intend to reach it. You essentially try to reach a variable on server which will be created at client-side, but the point where you intend to reach it is basically before your user sees anything in the browser.

1. You need to post your value to server-side via [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp).
2. You need a [server-side API function](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms) which is called when your command arrives to the server and send back the JSON you will need on client-side
3. In your [ajax callback](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) parse the response JSON.
4. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

"varName" is a client side variable, that's why you got that error.

If "inputBox" is server control, you can directly access it's value from ConvertTabletoString() method.

If not, use a hidden field with runat="server" and assign inputBox.value to it. So, you can access the hidden field value from your server method.